# Can I change class members using java reflection API?

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to  change any properties ( of a class , method or whatever )
using any java reflections ?

Comment: Have you even looked at the [web](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can even edit private members using reflection. Some libraries and frameworks (for example [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) and [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)) do this. I would not recommend doing this yourself however, unless you have a really good reason.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Something {
    private String name = "Hello";

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Something s = new Something();
        s.printName();

        Field field = s.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(s, "Goodbye");

        s.printName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnkx...even though it was a stupid qstn.. i was jus tryin to put a sample post :P

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at BeanUtils, which will allow you to do this without working directly with reflection. Much easier and less verbose:
http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

Some more documentation with examples: http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#package_description

Unless you really want to get your hands dirty with reflection, I would recommend to work with an abstraction layer like BeanUtils.